# How import flex iframe component?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

I am trying to import flex component but is not working.

mxml import:

[image]

Pom:

[image]

I need just import the component to use

```
 <flexiframe:IFrame id="googleIFrame"
                   label="Google"
                   source="http://www.google.com"
                   width="80%"
                   height="80%"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put only type swc and works properly.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.flex-iframe</groupId>
        <artifactId>flex-iframe</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
        <type>swc</type>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to use it in MXML, you need to add it to the namespace declaration in your MXML file.

```
xmlns:flexiframe="com.google.code.flexiframe"
```

It also looks like the import section you have has the wrong value, it should be `com.google.code.flexiframe.IFrame` not com.google.com... You only need this if it's going to be using it in the ActionScript code.